# Phase control universal motor dimmer

Tags: arduino, ac, motor-controller, dimmer, universal-motor

I need to control the speed of a 220v universal motor using arduino and I am thinking to use an atteny85 ic with a phase control circuit (ltv814 to detect zero crosses and moc3052 to drive a triac to clip the ac sine wave)

I found many example on the internet where people use the same method to control light bulbs and heaters

Will this way work with universal motors (that has brushes)?

If not what is the best way for that ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There are both Triac(noisier but longer brush life) and PWM types  (more efficient) cheap online.  WHat improvements did you have in mind?

Comment: Is there any ready to use module that works with arduino ?

Comment: The idea is to control the universal motor with a pc connected to arduino

Comment: Probably control a voltage instead of a pot. Go shop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a triac and a phase control circuit. However, some driving circuits may not work well for an inductive load. The gate current needs to persist long enough for the current to start flowing in the anode. Some driving circuits just use a narrow pulse, which will latch the triac for resistive loads, but can have issues with inductive loads.

Answer (score 0):

A phase control circuit is the simplest way to provide reasonably good speed control for a universal motor. Controlled rectifier control would probably be a little better than TRIAC control. A full-wave rectifier with a PWM control could also be used. That would probably be a little better than a controlled rectifier. How much difference there is between one method and another and exactly why one method might be better that another is hard to say, but a comparison can probably be found somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> I found many example on the internet where people use the same method to control light bulbs and heaters
>   Will this way work with universal motors (that has brushes)?
>   If not what is the best way for that ?

Its fine because its basically the same thing a SSR (solid state relay) does. Due to the inductive kick, the triac should have an inductive snubber circuit. Or have one built (alternistor or snubberless types they are called by from different manufacturers) in like the Q4040J7TP.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably work well. You have to detect zero cross and then fire the triac. Alternative method is to use an analog circuit as U2008B, then use PWM and optocopler for the speed setpoint.